# Swift ios parse json data get only selected data

Tags: ios, swift, parsing

Below is the code i tried to extract the JSON Object. I only want the Data with the status != Static and show that in `tableView`

```
postman response
[
    {
        "id": 249,
        "name": "aBrush your teeth",
        "desc": "Brush your teeth",
        "reward": "1.00",
        "sched": "2015-01-01T08:00:00+08:00",
        "parent": "",
        "type": "",
        "child": "",
        "occurrence": {
            "name": "once"
        },
        "status": {
            "name": "static"
        },
        "date_created": "2018-04-25T14:27:20.405928+08:00",
        "date_modified": "2018-04-26T11:56:02.030647+08:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 250,
        "name": "Brush your teeth",
        "desc": "Brush your teeth",
        "reward": "1.00",
        "sched": "2015-01-01T08:00:00+08:00",
        "parent": "",
        "type": "",
        "child": "",
        "occurrence": {
            "name": "once"
        },
        "status": {
            "name": "static"
        },
        "date_created": "2018-04-25T14:28:49.780354+08:00",
        "date_modified": "2018-04-26T11:56:05.616333+08:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 252,
        "name": "Brush your teeth",
        "desc": "Brush your teeth",
        "reward": "1.00",
        "sched": "2015-01-01T08:00:00+08:00",
        "parent": "",
        "type": "",
        "child": "",
        "occurrence": {
            "name": "once"
        },
        "status": {
            "name": "static"
        },
        "date_created": "2018-04-25T14:31:02.274405+08:00",
        "date_modified": "2018-04-26T11:59:57.676148+08:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 253,
        "name": "Brush your teeth",
        "desc": "Brush your teeth",
        "reward": "1.00",
        "sched": "2015-01-01T08:00:00+08:00",
        "parent": "",
        "type": "",
        "child": "",
        "occurrence": {
            "name": "once"
        },
        "status": {
            "name": "static"
        },
        "date_created": "2018-04-25T14:34:37.097498+08:00",
        "date_modified": "2018-04-26T09:42:24.633359+08:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 254,
        "name": "Brush your teeth",
        "desc": "Brush your teeths",
        "reward": "1.00",
        "sched": "2015-01-01T08:00:00+08:00",
        "parent": "",
        "type": "",
        "child": "",
        "occurrence": {
            "name": "once"
        },
        "status": {
            "name": "static"
        },
        "date_created": "2018-04-25T14:36:53.766088+08:00",
        "date_modified": "2018-04-26T11:56:15.757769+08:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 260,
        "name": "chorename",
        "desc": "{\n  \"questions\" : [\n    {\n      \"b\" : 2,\n      \"a\" : 1\n    },\n    {\n      \"b\" : 3,\n      \"a\" : 2\n    },\n    {\n      \"b\" : 2,\n      \"a\" : 8\n    },\n    {\n      \"b\" : 9,\n      \"a\" : 7\n    },\n    {\n      \"b\" : 3,\n      \"a\" : 6\n    }\n  ],\n  \"operation\" : \"+\"\n}",
        "reward": "1.00",
        "sched": "2018-04-19T15:54:24.657644+08:00",
        "parent": "shit",
        "type": "homework",
        "child": "",
        "occurrence": {
            "name": "once"
        },
        "status": {
            "name": "ongoing"
        },
        "date_created": "2018-04-26T10:13:42.913149+08:00",
        "date_modified": "2018-04-26T10:13:42.953485+08:00"
    }
]
```

code in getting the data
           // here i only want to get data from the dapi which status name != "static"
        and append it to getalldetail which is an  var getAllDetail: [[String:Any]] = [String:Any]

```
func demoApi() {
            Alamofire.request("test.api", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

                switch(response.result) {

                case .success(_):
                    guard let json = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]? else{ return}

                    print("Api Response : \(json)")

                    // here i only want to get data from the dapi which status name != "static"
                    for item in json {

                        self.getAllDetail.append(item)


                    }
                    if !self.getAllDetail.isEmpty{
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                    break

                case .failure(_):
                    print("Error")
                    break

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Would be good if you post the raw format of JSON, as this is not the correct JSON Response

Comment: Use filter method.

Comment: that is the response i got

Comment: @sharadchauhan can you post your asnwer so i can vote

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore that is the resposne from   guard let json = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]? else{ return}

                print("Api Response : \(json)")

Comment: @AkornDurnKurvirck : **so i can vote** - You don't vote directly. You first check if that works and is the right solution.

Comment: yeah that is if its correct then ill vote

Comment: Can you post the response you get using the PostMan.? As this seems to be wrong in JSON Validator

Comment: @AkornDurnKurvirck name is String type ?

Comment: yeah its a string

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore psotman respose [
    {
        "id": 249,
        "name": "aBrush your teeth",
        "desc": "Brush your teeth",
        "reward": "1.00",
        "sched": "2015-01-01T08:00:00+08:00",
        "parent": "",
        "type": "",
        "child": "",
        "occurrence": {
            "name": "once"
        },
        "status": {
            "name": "static"
        },
        "date_created": "2018-04-25T14:27:20.405928+08:00",
        "date_modified": "2018-04-26T11:56:02.030647+08:00"
    },
    {

Comment: Dont worry i just want to know to to get parse response where in the data that i only want is data which status != "static"

Comment: @AkornDurnKurvirck now you are posting different JSON format at comment. The above one is different.

Comment: that is just . the same so you know

Comment: @AkornDurnKurvirck Have added the answer, Hope that helps

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore i have vote your post , hope that helps too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply `filter` to your response as like below.

```
let filtered  = json.filter { (dict) -> Bool in
       guard let status : [String : String] = dict["status"] as? [String : String], let statusString = status["name"] else {
         return false
       }
      return statusString.compare("static") != .orderedSame
    }
```

Comment: how about apending that filtered data to getalldetail Sir

Comment: this is your filtered result. so just replaced it by `getAllDetail = filtered`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to take advantage of the `Codable` protocol of Swift 4 and decode the JSON into structs. This makes it very easy to filter the data. No type cast needed, no key subscription needed.

1. Create the structs

   ```
   struct ResponseData : Decodable {
       let id: Int
       let name, desc, reward : String
       let sched, parent, type, child : String
       let occurrence : Status
       let status : Status
       let dateCreated, dateModified : String
   }

   struct Status : Decodable {
       let name : String
   }
   ```
2. Your data source array `getAllDetail` must be declared as

   ```
   var getAllDetail = [ResponseData]()
   ```
3. In the `Alamofire` completion handler get the `data` and decode the JSON into the structs with `JSONDecoder`. The items can be filtered – pretty descriptively – with `filter{ $0.status.name == "static" }`

   ```
   Alamofire.request("test.api", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in

         switch(response.result) {

         case .success:
             guard let data = response.data else { return }

             let decoder = JSONDecoder()
             decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
             let result = try decoder.decode([ResponseData].self, from: data)
             self.getAllDetail = result.filter{ $0.status.name == "static" }

             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 self.tableView.reloadData()
             }

        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error", error)
        }
    }
   ```